# Is it possible to increase the depth of the Sphinx search page?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

[image: Sphinx search page]

The above image is the search feature of the Sphinx documentation generator.

As you can see in the image, the search page doesn't show the 'objects' under `Definitions` and `Orders`. Is there a setting which makes the search results one level deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume with `objects` you refer to a snippet of the article's text that contains the search hit ([example](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/search.html?q=text&check_keywords=yes&area=default)). Let's call it a *search summary*.

1) The length of the summary text the Sphinx search returns is hard-coded, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/static/searchtools.js_t) (function: `makeSearchSummary`, l. 457ff).
It's typical 240 characters long (plus two times `...`= 246).
To change this, you can [create your own Sphinx theme](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html#creating-themes) with a custom search function.

2) You possibly don't see any search summaries because you are opening the search locally on your file system. In such a case, the search is trying to request the files of search hits dynamically. Some browsers (i.e. Google Chrome) regard these requests as illegal `cross origin requests` and block them. Open the search in Firefox or Internet Explorer or try serving the files with a (local) static file server - for example with [sphinx-autobuild](https://github.com/GaretJax/sphinx-autobuild). Now, the search summary should be displayed.

3) There are [know issues](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1618) with the Sphinx search summary. And there is a [Sphinx extension trying to fix this](https://github.com/TimKam/sphinx-pretty-searchresults) (*Disclaimer: I wrote the extension*).

Comment: Regarding item 2: For me, both Firefox and Internet Explorer display search summaries when searching locally on the file system (Windows 7). And Firefox does it on Linux too.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, you are correct. Chrome doesn't (tried on Mac, Windows). I adjusted my answer.

Comment: I am getting the files from my browser, which is getting them directly from my local file system. It's not going through another program like a server. Unfortunately, the work computer i am on only has chrome and IE, and it would be a management nightmare to install more python software on my PC lol. Hmm...